# How can I paste the values ​of an array into another array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array called "valores". This array is divided into columns and within the columns their corresponding tasks (rows).

I have another array called "valValues" (the main one) that contains several arrays inside. It is also divided by columns first and within each column, its corresponding rows. The first element is the day of the month. The second element is the "Progress Bar". From the third element to the fifteenth element are empty rows where the values ​​of the "valores" array must be pasted.

How can I paste the values ​​from the "valores" array into the "valValues" array from the 3 column array element into the "valValues" array?

[image]

This is the code:

```
function importarTareasGlobal23(){

  ... // here is more code

  var filasDestino = sheetCalendario.getRangeList(['E4:E18', 'H4:H18', 'K4:K18', 'N4:N18', 'Q4:Q18', 'T4:T18', 'W4:W18', 'E20:E34', 'H20:H34', 'K20:K34', 'N20:N34', 'Q20:Q34', 'T20:T34', 'W20:W34', 'E36:E50', 'H36:H50', 'K36:K50', 'N36:N50', 'Q36:Q50', 'T36:T50', 'W36:W50', 'E52:E66', 'H52:H66', 'K52:K66', 'N52:N66', 'Q52:Q66', 'T52:T66', 'W52:W66', 'E68:E82', 'H68:H82', 'K68:K82', 'N68:N82', 'Q68:Q82', 'T68:T82', 'W68:W82', 'E84:E98', 'H84:H98', 'K84:K98', 'N84:N98', 'Q84:Q98', 'T84:T98', 'W84:W98']);
  var filasDestinoVal = filasDestino.getRanges();

  var tabladebusquedaVal = sheetTareas.getRange("B5:H" + lastRowTareas).getValues();

  var valValues = [];
  var valores = [];

  filasDestinoVal.forEach(row => {
    var val = row.getValues();
    valValues.push(val);
    
    ... // here is more code

    var resultados = [];

    tabladebusquedaVal.forEach(r => {
      ... // here is more code     
      if ( ... ) {
        resultados.push([icoTarea]);
      }
    });
    valores.push(resultados);
  });

  Logger.log(valores);
  Logger.log(valValues);
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Your sample image is your sample input values? For example, can you provide a sample table you want to use as the input situation, and provide the sample output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your expected result. I apologize for this.

Comment: Can you [edit] and paste those values in your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the JavaScript array methods splice(), slice(), or concat() to insert values from one array into another. For example, if you have two arrays, arr1 and arr2, you can use the splice() method to insert arr2 into arr1 as follows: arr1.splice(index, 0, ...arr2). Where index is the position where you want to insert values from arr2 into arr1.